# Explanation of configuration tags for GAE Apache Maven plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-gae-plugin

The documentation for Google's official GAE Apache Maven plugin (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) is quite incomplete. My current issue is that they do not explain the meaning of the following tags, as listed under **appengine:devserver**: `<fullScanSeconds>, <address>, <disableUpdateCheck>, <jvmFlags>, <port>, and <server>`. Can anyone please explain these? Some tags are obvious, like `<port>`, but some tags are ambiguous, such as the difference between `<address>` and `<server>` tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven plugin wraps the dev_appserver and appcfg scripts, so depending on the plugin goal you're running (i.e. devserver vs update) there are different parameters

These are the options available when running the local devserver - i.e mvn appengine:devserver
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments

fullScanSeconds is explained here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#Using_The_App_Engine_Maven_Plugin

These are the options available to different appcfg commands
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Command_Line_Arguments
They are contextual to the plugin operations, which are:

```
update, 
rollback,
enhance, 
devserver, 
devserver_start,
devserver_stop, 
set_default_version, 
vacuum_indexes,
update_dos, 
update_indexes, 
update_queues,
update_cron
backends_start, 
backends_delete, 
backends_stop, 
backends_configure, 
backends_rollback, 
backends_update, 
endpoints_get_discovery_doc, 
endpoints_get_client_lib,
```

Comment: How about `<jvmFlags>`? Is it flags for the appcfg.sh process or for the maven process?

Comment: Given appcfg is a shell script, my guess is jvmflags are passed to the devserver. I'm not quite sure how this works though, in the past I've seen that the devserver seems to be one app that spins up another, so jvmflags may be for the kickstart app, or the final devserver.

Comment: jvmFlags go to the final devserver.